# No matching function call when using vector push_back

Tags: c++, vector, graphics, sfml

Im using SFML and its Vector2f as well as a normal c++ vector.

Im using a class called projectiles, within is a default constructor and

```
///////////////////////////////////
//   Construct with position and velocities
//////////////////////////////////
projectile::projectile(const sf::Vector2f itsPosition, const sf::Vector2f itsVel):
position(itsPosition),
vel(itsVel)
{}
```

the call comes from main in the form of

```
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
    {
        projectiles.push_back(sf::Vector2f(rectPos), sf::Vector2f(10,10));
    }
```

leading to the error

```
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<projectile>::push_back(sf::Vector2<float>, sf::Vector2<float>)'|
```

do I need to let it initialize with the default constructor then edit after or is there something simple I'm missing here

Comment: probably it's better try to do like that `projectiles.push_back(projectile(sf::Vector2f(rectPos), sf::Vector2f(10,10)))` insted

Comment: I think you want `emplace_back`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much :D didnt realise I had to do that...

Comment: Use `emplace_back()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are passing two arguments to the push_back method, which is defined as only taking one argument. There is literally no definition for that function with more than one argument, so the compiler complains that you are looking for a method that doesn't exist. Source: (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)

What you actually need to do, is construct a new projectile, and then pass it back.

As immibis stated in his comment on your question, there is another method that might do what you want, emplace_back(). You may want to try changing the method to that instead. I've never used that method, so I can't say much beyond that. Source: (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/)

Comment: **emplace_back** constructs an instance in already available memory by calling [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) with placement. **std::vector** has often more memory reserved/capacity than used, so **emplace_back** just calls the class constructor on unused memory and the vector simply increases his size member. Using **push_back** with move semantic (as **segevara** did with a rvalue) isn't much more expensive.